# Why is a parameter needed for keydown events?

Tags: javascript

Why is it necessary to add a parameter for event handling? Like so:

```
  document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( e ) {
                        var keyCode = e.keyCode } );
```

Why do you need the '`e`' in there? why does the function need a parameter at all?

Comment: Because the function gets called with the event as argument.

Answer (score 2):

`e` stands for **event object**, which contains information about the fired event (event type, key code, event target, etc.). This object is passed to the handler function while event fires.

It's NOT mandatory. If you don't care which key is pressed, or any other information about the event, just skip the parameter, that's fine.

Even though you want the information, that parameter could be skipped as well. You could get it via `arguments[0]`, that's really up to you. It only makes the code less readable.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why would it change if you cared about knowing which key was pressed?

Comment: @nachime In fact, even though you want the information, you could still skip the paramter as well. Since you could get it via `arguments[0]`, that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event):

The  Event interface is accessible from within the handler function, via the event object passed as the first argument.

The following simple example shows how an event object is passed to the event handler function, and can be used from within one such function.

```
function foo(evt) {
  // the evt parameter is automatically assigned the event object
  alert(evt);
}
table_el.onclick = foo;
```

---

[source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm):

The event handler processing algorithm for an event handler H and an Event object E is as follows:

**1. Let callback be the result of getting the current value of the event
    handler H.**

**2. If callback is null, then abort these steps.**

**3. Process the Event object E as follows:**

> If E is an ErrorEvent object and the event handler IDL attribute's type is OnErrorEventHandler
>
> Invoke callback with five arguments, the first one having the value of E's message attribute, the second having the value of E's filename attribute, the third having the value of E's lineno attribute, the fourth having the value of E's colno attribute, the fifth having the value of E's error attribute, and with the callback this value set to E's currentTarget. Let return value be the callback's return value. [WEBIDL]

Otherwise

> Invoke callback with one argument, the value of which is the Event object E, with the callback this value set to E's currentTarget. Let return value be the callback's return value. [WEBIDL]

In this step, invoke means to run the jump to a code entry-point algorithm.

**4. Process return value as follows:**

> If the event type is mouseover
>   If the event type is error and E is an ErrorEvent object
>
> If return value is a Web IDL boolean true value, then cancel the event.
>   If the event type is beforeunload
>
> The event handler IDL attribute's type is OnBeforeUnloadEventHandler, and the return value will therefore have been coerced into either the value null or a DOMString.
>
> If the return value is null, then cancel the event.

Otherwise

> If the Event object E is a BeforeUnloadEvent object, and the Event object E's returnValue attribute's value is the empty string, then set the returnValue attribute's value to return value.

Otherwise

If return value is a Web IDL boolean false value, then cancel the event.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary..(but the event callback function is always called with event as an argument)

there are cases where you want to know which element triggered the event and what is the event. And some more information.. In your example `e.keycode` is useful to determine which key was pressed.

There are many methods on that argument, such as `preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of event or `e.target` to get the target which triggered event.. So you need the argument e to be passed as function parameter.

If you dont require it just dont pass it as an argument